# Plotting a family of functions with For

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot a family of functions differing only by a constant $c$. The function is: $2x^2-5x+c$. In order to plot them I'm using the following code:

```
Plot[For[i = 0, i < 4, i++, {2 x^2 - 5 x + i}], {x, -5, 5}]
```

but there's no output besides the axis. The `i`inside the loop `For` is equivalent to the constant $c$ of the function. How can I plot them using the `For` loop inside the `Plot` command? Is this possible?

Comment: Look up `Table`.  `For` is rarely used in *Mathematica* (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica).

Comment: How would my code turn if I use `Table`?

Comment: `For` returns `Null`, always. So there is nothing to plot. Do as Michael E2 instructs you.

Comment: Ok, now I got it! Thank you very much.

Comment: The last example under "Basic Examples" in the [docs for Plot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) shows how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Table[
 Plot[2 x^2 - 5 x + i, {x, -5, 5}], 
 {i, 0, 3}]
```

or if you want them all on the same axes:

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@Table[2 x^2 - 5 x + i, {i, 0, 3}], 
 {x, -5, 5}]
```